# Send unwanted Char's to end of array

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, char

Let's say we have a string

```
String data = "<span> 0397]);}}:;)]</span>";
```

Then we send that into an char array

```
Char[] charData = data.ToCharArray();
```

How could I go trough this data and replace all unwanted data to the end of the array but move all data left one from the current char that has been moved to make room at the end for the unwanted data.

```
Char[] sendToEnd = { ';', ')', '}', ']' };
```

I have tried a loop but it causes an infinite loop when it loops over the already swapped data.

In the end the string data should be

```
"<span> 0397</span>]);}}:;)]"
```

Comment: If it's unwanted, then why do you still want it? :)

Comment: well its both wanted and unwanted, its not wanted in the span but its still needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = new String(data.Where(c => !sendToEnd.Contains(c))
                         .Concat(data.Where(c => sendToEnd.Contains(c)))
                         .ToArray());
```

Also declaring `sendToEnd` as

```
var sendToEnd = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { ';', ')', '}', ']' });
```

can give a better performance

Comment: I had a solution all typed up but this is so much more elegant.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing please? Also what is a Hashset<>?

Comment: First `data.Where` returns *wanted* data, second one returns *unwanted* data. I concat them (like list1+list2) and convert to char array by `ToArray`, and give that array to `new string` constructor. Similar to: `new String((wanted+unwanted).ToArray())`

Comment: both data.Where give the error "Error 2 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @L.B Thanks, first time VS has not shown the "resolve issue" in the right click menu.

Comment: It is a bad idea to have cascading Lambda expressions. This adds complexity, and if you want to remember your own code, you should write it out and include comments. Just a tip.

Comment: @CalebKeith if it is not your own opinion, please post some links so that everyone get benefit of it.

Comment: It isn't an opinion, it is a best practice. Try to read someone elses code that cascades Lambda expressions. This is just a simple string operation, doing something even more complex would blind you. It is a general understanding of C#, I don't need a reference for this.

Comment: @CalebKeith why do you think I asked him to explain what it's doing? or was that aimed at L.B

Comment: That was aimed at LB, I understood why you asked and that is why I pointed that out to him. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of initially moving the characters to the end, move them to another array and join the arrays to form the final string.

Comment: This would work but the answer I choose is a cleaner method + 1 for correct answer though